# Trying to create clean URLs but getting some errors

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to create beauty url from htaccess this is my code

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ /$1/ [R]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ /user.php?username=$1
```

I want to display user data like this but problem is when i run anyother file like domain.com/contactus this redirects to user.php?username=contactus Also on this expression `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` i want to put (.) Dot because there are usernames like john.dyer to is this expression correct - `[a-zA-Z0-9_.]`

this is my user.php

```
<?php
$username = $_GET["username"];
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `users` WHERE  `username` =  '$username'");
$r = mysql_fetch_array($data); 
$query_username                      = $r["username"];

if($query_username == $username)
{
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/welcome/index.php';
}
?>
```

Sorry I'm very new to this..I'm learning this things so please tell me if there is any better way to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a quite a few problem, try this modified code:

```
RewriteEngine On

## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]

# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /user.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Working good but still i'm getting lil error on this regex with (.) like if i give username = somthing.something.123 it says not found but the username is their on database and thanks for helping

Comment: Test in a new browser. It internally forwards `/123` to: `/user.php?username=123`

Comment: No, I'm sorry but i think you;re not getting me.. i said if the username is ( facebook.com/anubhava.123 ) it should put username=anubhava.123

Comment: Last rule is making `/somthing.123` to `/user.php?username=somthing.123` **internally**. Do you want URL to show this change in browser also?

Comment: Please kindly come on twitter i messaged you